# Images are not showing in my wordpress website page?

Tags: php, wordpress

[Check out The link for the page where images are not showing](http://www.http://sparkeighteen.com/our-team/)

The code for this section is as follow:

```
 [ut_quote_rotator_alt]

 [ut_quote author="Founder/Director" avatar="http://sparkeighteen.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Website_AayushNarang.jpg"] Aayush Narang [/ut_quote]

 [ut_quote author="Brand Partner" avatar="http://sparkeighteen.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Website_AmishaDuggal.jpg"] Amisha Duggal[/ut_quote]

 [ut_quote author="Account Lead" avatar="http://sparkeighteen.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Website_EshaanRevis.jpg"] Eshaan K. Revis [/ut_quote]

 [ut_quote author="Account Lead" avatar="http://sparkeighteen.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Website_Shweta_Nigam.jpg"] Shweta Nigam[/ut_quote]

 [ut_quote author="Copy Lead" avatar="http://sparkeighteen.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Website_DevKhanna.jpg"]Dev D Khanna[/ut_quote]

 [ut_quote author="Creative Lead" avatar="http://sparkeighteen.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Website_PratikshaRao.jpg"] Pratiksha Rao[/ut_quote]

 [ut_quote author="Graphic Design" avatar="http://sparkeighteen.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Website_RajanDhingra.jpg"] Rajan Dhingra [/ut_quote]

 [ut_quote author="Content Analyst" avatar="http://sparkeighteen.com/wp- content/uploads/2015/09/Website_SanjanaSinha.jpg"] Sanjana Sinha[/ut_quote]

 [ut_quote author="Technology" avatar="http://sparkeighteen.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Website_AyushMiglani.jpg"] Ayush Miglani [/ut_quote]

 [/ut_quote_rotator_alt]
```

[image: link to images]

This is one of the images that i have to display:

Comment: Above Given link is misspelled.... Sorry for that.... Here is the link to the page : http://sparkeighteen.com/our-team/

Comment: It looks like the attribute data-src has the correct image paths, switch src and data-src